# php regex to get middle of string

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

I parse an html page into a plain text in order to find and get a numeric value.
In the whole html mess, I need to find a string like this one:

```
C) Debiti33.197.431,90I - Di finanziamento
```

I need the number 33.197.431,90 (where this number is going to change on every html parsing request.

Is there any regex to achieve this? For example:

```
STARTS WITH 'C) Debiti' ENDS WITH 'I - Di finanziamento' GETS the middle string that can be whatever.
```

Whenever I try, I get empty results...don't know that much about regex.
Can you please help me?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
^C\) Debiti\K.*?(?=I - Di finanziamento$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fM7uA5/9)

PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$mystring = "C) Debiti33.197.431,90I - Di finanziamento";
$regex = '~^C\) Debiti\K.*?(?=I - Di finanziamento$)~';
if (preg_match($regex, $mystring, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?> //=> 33.197.431,90
```

Comment: Thank you. With your regex I get the beginning and the end of the string, but not the number I am looking for. What am I missing?

Comment: it works for me. see the above code. You may just copy and paste the above code in a file and then run it.

Comment: thanks! I managed to get it working before your code, but any way, thank you again. What still remains unsolved is why if the string is just "C) Debiti33.197.431,90I - Di finanziamento", it works perfectly, but if I do a whole search in a long webpage, where that string is contained, I get a white page (no results).

Comment: if `C) Debiti33.197.431,90I` present at the middle of a page then it won't work because we already gave start and end patterns in the original pattern.

Comment: Oh...that's bad news. I could extract the string "C) Debiti33.197.431,90I - Di finanziamento" from the whole html, couldn't I? Maybe deleting everything is before the words "C) Debiti" and after the words "I - Di finanziamento". The problem is...how  :(

Comment: why do you want to delete? just extract the matched charcters. see http://regex101.com/r/fM7uA5/10

Comment: Your solution is ok. In the parsed web page I get someting like condensed text. Example: "Spesa pubblica34.454.564,00C) Debiti33.197.431,90I - Di finanziamento154.236.452,00" . In that case, your solution doesn't work, neither does @user3218114's one. I rapidly solved by exploding the whole html page in proximity of C) Debiti an I - Di Finanziamento so I get the numebr I want. That's it. Raw, totally not elegant, but working. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Read section [Want to Be Lazy? Think Twice.](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html)

```
(?<=\bC\) Debiti)[\d.,]+(?=I - Di finanziamento\b)
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fM7uA5/12)

sample code:

```
$re = "/(?<=\\bC\\) Debiti)[\\d.,]+(?=I - Di finanziamento\\b)/i";
$str = "C) Debiti33.197.431,90I - Di finanziamento";

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```