# How to remove some letters on my text output?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to remove some characters or text on my output. How can I do that? I have this value:

```html
<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['btnSubcode'])) 
  {
    $lblCode = isset($_POST['lblQrTxt']) ? $_POST['lblQrTxt'] : '';
  }
?>

<input type="text" id="card-code" value='<?php echo $lblCode ?>' class="form-control">
```

Its value is:

```
QR Code: 444444444|123
```

I want to remove `QR Code:` and `|  123`. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Probably using `preg_match()` http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php

Comment: You can use a regex. The syntax is quite different depending on whether you want to do this in PHP or JS though. I'd suggest PHP.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan hello sir, can you please help me with it? im not familiar with `regex` im having a hard time on it thank you

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134446/php-regex-to-get-middle-of-string). You could also potentially use `substr()` if the required indexes of the string are constant.

Comment: @executable hello, i think it will not work because i think preg_match() works only for STATIC or FIXED letters

Comment: What do you mean by *fixed* or *static* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the input is always the same structure, `QR Code: value|value`, you can use the `explode` function [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
  $code = "QR Code: 444444444|123";
  $code = explode(":",$code); // code = array("QR Code","444444444|123")
  $code = explode("|",$code[1]); // code[1] = "444444444|123"
  $code1 = trim($code[0]) // 444444444
  $code2 = trim($code[1]) // 123
```

Comment: hey this might be an answer but what if I omnly want the `123` to show??

Comment: iv'e edit my answer for you comment, explode return an array in the first element will be the left side and in the second element will be the right side of the string around the explode delimiter (see the docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Explode the string twice - once to get rid of the QR code text and one to get the actual code - ie: before the pipe (|)

```php
<?php 
  if (isset($_POST['btnSubcode'])) 
  {
    $lblCodeTotal = isset($_POST['lblQrTxt']) ? $_POST['lblQrTxt'] : '';

    $lblCodePortions1 = explode("QR Code: ", $lblCodeTotal); // gives 444444444|123
    $lblCodePortions2 = explode("|", $lblCodePortions1[1]); // gives 444444444

    $lblCode = $lblCodePortions2[0];
  }
?>
```

Comment: That's only because it's a JS snippet attempting to run PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
   $ourput = rtrim(ltrim($lblCode, 'QR Code:'), '|123') ;
```

Comment: great it works!! but the number `123` is still there

Comment: how can we remove the `123` sir?

Comment: try now please, i forgot about 123

Comment: i have one more problem sir  what if the output changed to `12343594` :( is there any solution to that?

Comment: No problem, your output will work fine if the following string will not change 
'QR Code:' and '|123'

Answer (score 0):

You could add this JavaScript after your PHP code:

```
document.getElementById("card-code").value = document.getElementById("card-code").value.split("QR Code: ")[0].split("|123")[0];
```

Comment: hey mate !! please help me how can i put that into my input type = text please that is the answer i need

Answer (score 0):

You can use "substr(string,start,length)" function in order to find the start and end point for the string itself.

```
<?php
    $mystring = "QR Code: 444444444|123";
    $mystring = substr($mystring, strpos($mystring, ':') +1);
    $mystring = substr($mystring, 0, strpos($mystring, '|'));
    echo $mystring;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it removes the QR code first then split them by 'explode' with | as delimiter

```
 $output = explode(ltrim($lblCode, 'QR Code:'), '|')[0] ;
```